# Incrementing a php session within a JS conidtion

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
this.collision = function(p1, p2, p3, p4)
{
    if(this.ballY - this.radius + this.dy <= p1.height && this.ballX + this.dx >= p1.leftPostx - p1.goalPostRadius && this.ballX <= p1.rightPostx + p1.goalPostRadius)
    {
        this.dy = -this.dy;
        this.ballY = p1.height + this.radius;
        count++;
        score++;
        <?php $_SESSION['score'] += 1; ?>
    }
    else if(this.ballY + this.radius + this.dy >= canvas.height - p2.height && this.ballX + this.dx >= p2.leftPostx - p2.goalPostRadius && this.ballX + this.dx <= p2.rightPostx + p2.goalPostRadius)
    {
        this.dy = -this.dy;
        this.ballY = canvas.height - p2.height - this.radius;
        count++;
        score++;
        <?php $_SESSION['score'] += 1; ?>
    }
    else if(this.ballX + this.radius + this.dx >= canvas.width - p3.height && this.ballY + this.dy >= p3.topPosty - p3.goalPostRadius && this.ballY + this.dy <= p3.bottomPosty + p3.goalPostRadius)
    {
        this.dx = -this.dx;
        this.ballX = canvas.width - p3.height - this.radius;
        count++;
        score++;
        <?php $_SESSION['score'] += 1; ?>
    }
    else if(this.ballX - this.radius + this.dx <= p4.height && this.ballY + this.dy >=  p4.topPosty - p4.goalPostRadius && this.ballY + this.dy <= p4.bottomPosty + p4.goalPostRadius)
    {
        this.dx = -this.dx;
        this.ballX = p4.height + this.radius;
        count++;
        score++;
        <?php $_SESSION['score'] += 1; ?>
    }
    else if(this.ballY - this.radius + this.dy < 0 || this.ballY + this.radius + this.dy > canvas.height || this.ballX - this.radius + this.dx < 0 || this.ballX + this.radius + this.dx > canvas.width)
    {
        checkLives(p1, p2, p3, p4, ball1);
    }
}
```

So, the title says it all. In this code I am trying to use a javascript condition to determine when I will be incrementing my session variable. How can I do this? Thanks in advance for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible like this way. When ever your script ready and load then and there php code will execute so does not depends on your js function call or js conditions. Always remember php is server side scripting language and JavaScript is client side scripting.

You can try it using ajax or jquery post.

Try like this way..

If you are not added jQuery library file then you can add it in your header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now your code is:

```
var myObj = new function(){
    this.collision = function(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    {
        if(this.ballY - this.radius + this.dy <= p1.height && this.ballX + this.dx >= p1.leftPostx - p1.goalPostRadius && this.ballX <= p1.rightPostx + p1.goalPostRadius)
        {
            this.dy = -this.dy;
            this.ballY = p1.height + this.radius;
            count++;
            score++;
        }
        else if(this.ballY + this.radius + this.dy >= canvas.height - p2.height && this.ballX + this.dx >= p2.leftPostx - p2.goalPostRadius && this.ballX + this.dx <= p2.rightPostx + p2.goalPostRadius)
        {
            this.dy = -this.dy;
            this.ballY = canvas.height - p2.height - this.radius;
            count++;
            score++;
        }
        else if(this.ballX + this.radius + this.dx >= canvas.width - p3.height && this.ballY + this.dy >= p3.topPosty - p3.goalPostRadius && this.ballY + this.dy <= p3.bottomPosty + p3.goalPostRadius)
        {
            this.dx = -this.dx;
            this.ballX = canvas.width - p3.height - this.radius;
            count++;
            score++;
        }
        else if(this.ballX - this.radius + this.dx <= p4.height && this.ballY + this.dy >=  p4.topPosty - p4.goalPostRadius && this.ballY + this.dy <= p4.bottomPosty + p4.goalPostRadius)
        {
            this.dx = -this.dx;
            this.ballX = p4.height + this.radius;
            count++;
            score++;

        }
        else if(this.ballY - this.radius + this.dy < 0 || this.ballY + this.radius + this.dy > canvas.height || this.ballX - this.radius + this.dx < 0 || this.ballX + this.radius + this.dx > canvas.width)
        {
            checkLives(p1, p2, p3, p4, ball1);
        }

        myObj.updateCore(score);
    }
    this.updateCore = function(addIncrement){
            jQuery.ajax({
              dataType: "json", 
              method:"POST",
              url:PATH_TO_FILE+'/serverfile.php',
              data:{score:addIncrement},
              async:false,
              beforeSend:function(){},
              success:function(data){},
              error:function(request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
              },
              complete: function(){}
            });  
        }   
    }
```

in serverfile.php

```
<?php 

$_SESSION['score'] = $_POST['score'];

?>
```

Comment: So, hopefully I am understanding this correctly. This now posts the value of the JS score variable to serverfile.php which then updates the session, correct? Wouldn't I also need a session_start() in the serverfile.php or no?

Comment: I don't know your framework you are using if in any file of your code coming before this file included session start is initiated then no need to start session, if not then you should start session.

Comment: im not currently using any framework. just raw html, php and js if that makes sense.

Comment: so please add session start before using session.